# Wait 6 seconds then do something

Tags: java, android

i have a `CountDownTimer`, which overrides `onFinish` like this :

```
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (v != null) {
                v.setText("Finished");
            }

        }
```

What i want to do is, that once the timer calls `onFinish` this method should wait like 6 seconds and then execute its code.

Pseudcode

```
onFinish(){
     setText("SOMETHING);
     wait6Seconds;
     then do something else;
}
```

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Why not add 6 seconds to your countdown timer?

Comment: Then use `Handler.postDelayed` method for doing something after `wait6Seconds `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something after 6 second
    }
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(6000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.i("Interrupted Exception", e.toString());
}
```

in an AsyncTask

Comment: this works but not as good as the answer from Dhaval.The code setText("BLA"); is not executed

Comment: @DhavalPatel - Forgot to add that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep (6000); should take care if it.